# Connection Refused : While Running the Docker Compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am new baby to the Docker. I am using docker within the spring boot application. Below is my file .

Application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DATABASE_HOST}:3306/${DATABASE_NAME}?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=true
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
server.port=8443
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM openjdk:latest
ADD target/app.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8443
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=docker"]
```

Docker Compose :

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mysqlDb:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=springdemo
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - DATABASE_HOST= 192.168.0.1
    volumes:
      - /data/mysql
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    container_name: mysql-db

  springbootdocker:
    image: xyz/signup
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysqlDb
    links:
      - mysqlDb   
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST= mysqlDb
      - DATABASE_USER=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
      - DATABASE_NAME=springdemo
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD","curl","-f","http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s 
      retries: 3
```

**1st part of Issue is Resolved :**
when i run the App , i get the following error :

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.



Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${DATABASE_HOST}
```

**1) What i am trying to Achieve -**

- Want to create a jar for my application.
- After creating a jar , i want to create the image from the jar
- After creating the image of the application , i want to push into the docker hub .
- From other server , I will run docker-compose.yml file . It will fetch the mysql and image from the docker hub and run the application in the other port as mentioned in the docker-compose.

Hope I am clear ,what i want to acheive .

**Here comes the problem :**

- when i am trying to run the application locally , i am able to create the jar only when ,i write this line in application.properties class.

  **spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/springdemo?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=true**

I am able to create the jar and after that image to -> upload that image to docker hub , when i am running the docker-compose able to pull that image but can't able to connect to the mysql workbench.

- So,I thought, I am running the docker-compose in diffrent System/Server. There ip address is different.

  So, I changed the url to this :

**spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.1:3306/springdemo?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=true**

where

```
192.168.0.1 - this ip is for the diffrent server, where i want to run the docker-compose file
```

But when i am running the spring boot application , I am unable to run the application because it's saying the almost the same error as mentioned above i.e Connection refuse . So i am unable to create the jar so , unable to create the image . So my idea fails here also.

- Then Again, One idea again come into my mind , can't we put the dynamic ip address in application.properties file,so i tried this line :

**spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DATABASE_HOST}:3306/${DATABASE_NAME}?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=true**

DATABASE_HOST- you can find it in docker-compose file

I thought may be this one : ${DATABASE_HOST} , will pick the value of the DATABASE_HOST from the docker-compose .

But my idea failed , I am getting the error as mentioned in top while running the application. can't able to create jar ,so unable to create the image .

**2nd Part - Issue is still Open**

when i am able to run the docker-compose in my local terminal , and able to create the container . I can also see mysql is connected as well as my schema .
But when i am trying to access my API using postman or web browser then , it's saying not connected

```
http://localhost:8080/dockerex
```

Inside my Controller Class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/dockerex")
public class SpringBootDockerController {

    @GetMapping
    public String check() {
        return "checking";
    }
}
```

when i inspect my container , ip address is coming blank : snapshot of conatiner :

```
[
 {
     "Id": "7664bab5ed452e3e2243e1802010240ab5a3eb817af6164e985b10e729ff4c8f",
     "Created": "2020-02-04T17:30:08.5351511Z",
     "Path": "java",
     "Args": [
         "-jar",
         "app.jar",
         "--spring.profiles.active=docker"
     ],
     "State": {
         "Status": "running"
.......................
"PortBindings": {
             "8080/tcp": [
                 {
                     "HostIp": "",
                     "HostPort": "8080"
                 }
             ]
         },
```

Answer (score 2):

Good it worked but here you see you were using DB_HOST earlier, now you are using DATABASE_HOST= mysqlDb , which is currently pointing to your mysql service name.
this service name can be discovered within the single network created by docker compose.
You were hardcoding DB_HOST=192.168.0.1 and trying to connect using this IP , which is invalid as docker compose create its network.

Comment: Thanks for your time . I can write this one in docker-compose ,- DATABASE_HOST= 192.168.0.1 right? I am new to it , if you guide me it's right or wrong

Comment: If you want to assign some specific ip address then you have to create a network and then assign containers to that network with specific ip address within your cidr. I am editing my answer for your reference docker-compose file , as in comment i cannot paste yaml file.

Comment: I am not able to paste docker-compose.yaml in yaml format. you can refer to below link for your docker-compose file

https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-static-ip-container-linux-to-mac/42513

Comment: I run my docker-compose locally on my terminal , i can see my container is running but i am unable to run my api . It's not connecting to https://localhost/8080 .I inspected the container also , u can see my updated code above

Comment: try to run this curl http://localhost:8080/dockerex inside your container and see the response

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention service name here as in your case db service name is **mysqlDb**. Below is the updated application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://$(DB_HOST:mysqlDb):3306/springdemo?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=true
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
server.port=8443
```

Comment: getting the same error while running the spring boot application : Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: $(DB_HOST:mysqlDb)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Replace `DB_HOST= 192.168.0.7` to `DB_HOST= mysqldb` in your docker-compose file.

And update your application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://$(DB_HOST:mysqlDb):3306/springdemo?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=true
```

to this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://$(mysqlDb):3306/springdemo?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=true
```

Comment: Same Error I am getting , i have updated the code also ,and made changes according to you ,but still i am getting this message : Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${mysqlDb}

Comment: just a small question , are you sure about this parameter DB_HOST ? You are trying to give a static ip but according to documentation : By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

Comment: earlier it is DB_HOST , I updated my code . Now it's refer to DATABASE_HOST. But Nothing going in my way ,same error

Comment: As example lets take this scenario for web application and a postgres:

version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"

Each container can now look up the hostname web or db and get back the appropriate container’s IP address. For example, web’s application code could connect to the URL postgres://db:5432 and start using the Postgres database.As simple as that try to implement like this , hope you will get your solution.

Comment: I want to know that , running the docker-compose will come later , first need to run the springboot application to create a jar ,after creating a jar , i can create a image , then i put this image on docker hub then only i can run my docker-compose ,right ? . But my 1st step is only failing . I am unable to create a jar

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone : I got the solution by hit and trail :P

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DATABASE_HOST:localhost}:${DATABASE_PORT:3306}/springdemo?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=true
```